# Pass select query from the client side

Tags: javascript, database

Is it OK (I mean security reasons) to pass database query (select or update or whatever) to the server side as parameter (like, I read the values of the form fields, form a query string in javascript and pass the formed string to the server as a parameter):

```
$.ajax({
    url : "servletURL",
    type : "post",
    data: {query: "select name, last_name from employees"},
    success: //do things
});
```

or

```
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var last_name = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
$.ajax({
    url : "servletURL",
    type : "post",
    data: {query: "select * from employees where name="+name+" and last_name="+last_name},
    success: //do things
});
```

Or should I pass to the server only parameters, not full queries, and make prepared statement there?

And surely, I can check the validity of the field values before I send the request to the server.

Comment: pass only parameter to get faster response otherwise u have perform more coding work for this

Comment: Ideally all you would need from the user are *values*, not *queries*.  Unless your application is specifically for the purpose of allowing users to execute code (such as writing a PHPMyAdmin clone) then why would you ever want users writing their own code for your server to execute?

Comment: POST the values and verify & escape the values on the server side before building the query there.

Comment: doing this you could be vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: @BeNdErR I agree, the second example is vulnerable (if I don't check field values for symbols like semicolon). What about the first one?

Comment: @keshet: The first one still looks like SQL code.  Why wouldn't it be just as vulnerable as the second one?  If you plan to taking user input and executing it as code, that's SQL injection.  Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @keshet it's still vulnerable as the semicolon could be encoded with something different than ";", resulting as valid and reaching your server

Comment: @keshet The first is vulnerable too, as it may be complemented by a `union all select anything_1 name, anything_2 last_name from anywhere_else`.

Comment: @David in the first variant I don't take any input from the user. It's when I need to form a predefined table and fill it with data from database.

Comment: @keshet client side code is easily modifiable, even if it does not allow user input.

Comment: @keshet: Where is this JavaScript code running?  In the user's web browser?  Then in *both* scenarios you take input from the user.  The server is literally *asking the user* for a SQL query to execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're building something that is explicitly for executing queries on a database (PHPMyAdmin, or such), it is **NEVER** okay to do this.

Why?
A malicious user can now delete your **ENTIRE** database, simply by editing the javascript.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "",
  type: "post",
  data: {query: "DROP database"},
  success:
  })
```

The best practice is to send the data to the server, and construct your query over there.
The only attack that is left is SQL-injection. Solutions for this are specific to each language, but you can have a look at [Tom Scott's explanation on it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jKylhJtPmI).

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass queries as parameters. Best avoid even using query templates. The security holes are gaping wide and to close them you effectively need a full-fledged sql parser in your validation code.

In your example, just imagine a man-in-the-middle attack 
that changes the instantiated query

```
select * from employees where name='<name>' and last_name='<last_name>'
```

to

```
select * from employees where name='<name>' and last_name='<last_name>'
union all
select * from employees
```

by simply appending a constant string